# Is there a way to maintain, using AWS services, an all time available list of pre populated random id's (UUID)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

A piece of code generates UUIDs. Another piece of code, running in an AWS Lambda, need to use few, say 5, random UUID out of these already generated UUID's. Any suggestion or advice, please?

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are creating UUIDs in advance, and not simply doing this on demand?

Comment: @jarmod Problem which I am trying solve is: There is a piece of code which generates rows in DynamoDb table with UUIDs as key. Another piece of code needs to pull random records in batches of 10 with very minimal possibility of pulling the records duplicated in batches. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be for the process that is originally generating the UUIDs and inserting items into DynamoDB to also send each UUID to an SQS queue. That would allow a consumer application to [get a batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html) of UUIDs and process them. The consumer would process its batch of UUIDs and then delete them from the SQS queue. While the consumer is processing its batch of UUIDs, they are not visible to any other SQS consumer so you won't see multiple consumers processing the same UUIDs.

Comment: This is expected to be a never-ending list, which I can handle by reinserting the message to the queue. Use case needs to select some RANDOM id's from that list so as those records can be fetched from the queue - again and again - by any number of threads/lambda requests.

Comment: Ok so SQS won’t provide the random access pattern that you want. Might help to share more about what your app is doing and why it needs this access pattern.

Comment: the app needs to render the records on a UI in random order, and many users will be accessing this data in random order.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some sort of persistent storage for this, as in storing generated UUIDs and then their status (used/unused).
A good option would be AWS DynamoDB, due to its excellent integration with AWS Lambda. You can [start here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html)

Comment: cannot mark the status used/unused as these id's need to be used again and again by multiple instances running in parallel. This is a never exhausting kind of list. So in above solution, I may end up pulling all the records and then logic to select random elements.

Answer (score 0):

As of now the solution I am using (will update once I figure out an optimized approach)

> Created a table in RDS (Relation Database) with only one column and
>   used it to store only the id of the actual object stored in DynamoDB.
>   A SQL query to pull random records from RDS table is simple and that
>   too not very costly in comparison of using queues and applying logic
>   to queues to maintain the randomization.